# Whats the best way to run a python script concurrently?

Tags: python, mysql, ruby, multithreading, sidekiq

I have a simple python script that I need to run multiple instances of all storing data to the same table? Its a simple script but must run extremely fast selecting and inserting as fast as mysql can handle it.

I have been getting recommendations for messaging queue like sidekiq informed that it would work great and didn't matter if my scripts were in python and not ruby. Just run the script as a sidekiq worker and let sidekiq to the work.

Any thoughts or links?

Comment: The lack of more profound information regarding your question led to a very vague question in a model not really suited for Q&A. Try to elaborate more, provide some examples our code snippets of what you're trying to accomplish. That seems to be an interesting topic and i would gladly help.

Comment: Your question is extremely broad and will generate a number of opinions  making it off-topic. If you have a specific programming problem we can help.